# How to set up build target to release and the solution in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to follow the steps of Github as following. But I don't know how to conduct the 2.and 3.step

To build the solution using the Visual Studio:
1.Open the UXI.GazeToolkit.sln in Visual Studio.
2.Set up build target to Release.
3.Build the solution (default hotkey F6).

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+B is to build in VS

Answer (score 0):

1. On the toolbar, choose Release from the Solution Configurations list
2. then press the green start button
   [image]